# Too much positional argument error when calling abstract base class method in child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I have following piece of code:

```
from abc import ABC

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def xpath():
    return By.XPATH, '//*'


class BasePage(ABC):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self._driver = driver
        self._driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self._wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    def wait_for_page_to_load(self):
        self._wait.until(self._is_page_ready)

    def click_something(self):
        self._driver.find_element(*xpath()).click()
        self.wait_for_page_to_load()

    def _is_page_ready(self):
        state = self._driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;")
        return state == "complete"


class ChildPage(BasePage):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)


c = ChildPage(webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
c._driver.get("http://google.com")
c.click_something()
```

it results in error:

> TypeError: _is_page_ready() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Any clues why it doesn't work? Workaround is to make _is_page_ready as static, but this syntax doesn't look incorrect, so I'm curious why it throwing this error.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with ABC or inheritance, you're just passing a callback function (the bound method `self._is_page_ready`) with the wrong signature to `self._wait.until`. It wants to pass one argument, you expect none. Read the library docs to figure out what that argument will be.

Comment: Which one library docs, Selenium Webdriver? I read it, I found nothing related.

Comment: The example given [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) (under Custom Wait Conditions) suggests the driver gets passed to the callback (which it suggests should be a callable class, but that doesn't seem necessary). Try adding an additional argument to `_is_page_ready` (that you can ignore) and see if it helps?

Comment: You are right, something like this works: `def _is_page_ready(self, x):` and I see in debug that x is a WebDriver. But why WebDriverWait object is passing WebDriver object to _is_page_ready function? I'm not sure what is defining that in code

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
TypeError: _is_page_ready() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

...implies that the `_is_page_ready()` is defined to take one positional argument:

```
def click_something(self):
```

where as, within the method you are additionally trying to access *`driver`* as:

```
state = self._driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;")
```

You need to pass the *`driver`* as a parameter as well:

```
def _is_page_ready(self, driver):
    state = self._driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;")
    return state == "complete"
```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB it's correct, I'm trying to access driver, but I'm getting driver from existing object (self) and don't want to pass additional driver as parameter. So the only solution here is to change signature to `(self, driver)` and not use it?

Comment: Ok, I realized that until method in wait is passing driver to method which we are passing to until. It's visible in WebDriverWait class.